# Sandcastle xslt

Tags: .net, documentation-generation, sandcastle

How do I change the output of a Sandcastle built website using xslt? Are there any tutorials on how to do this?

I can go in and change the css but this seems a little the wrong way around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandcastle is open source, so you have the chance to tune it to suit your needs,

http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

From its source code you can see which parts are used to generate the web site, and then you can make whatever changes you like.